# Error: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values" when populating dynamic DropDownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added two DropDownList controls programatically. When the first DropDownList's index is changed the second DropDownList should get populated. The first DropDown gets populated on Page Load.

When I select an item from the first DropDown, a DataTable is filled with values that need to be populated in the second DropDown. On setting the breakpoint I found that DataTable is filling properly.

But when it reaches line:

```
ddl.DataSource = dt;
```

it gives error:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values
```

I also found that ddl is picking the right DropDown.

The problem I find is that while postback some error is happening.

I tried even doing:

```
dd.Items.Add("abcd");
```

Comment: Do you recreated *both* DropDownList controls on the postback?

Comment: I created only once at the start.

Comment: Dynamic controls have to be recreated on every postback. I think this error is happening due to control not found.